# How to reverse python recursion print order without interrupting inputs

Tags: python, recursion

I am working a project for school where I need to use recursion for a given number of test cases without the use of any for or while loops to print the sums of the square of non-negative integers. The issues is that there is suppose to be no output until after all of the inputs for each test case is input and it need to print in the order of the input. Example:

```
Number of Test Cases: 3

Test Case #1 Number of Nums to sum: 5
Testcase #1 Nums to Sum: 7 14 2 3 5 = 283

Test Case #2 Number of Nums to sum: 4
Testcase #2 Nums to Sum: 3 1 7 2 = 63

Test Case #2 Number of Nums to sum: 3
Testcase #3 Nums to Sum:  2 2 6 = 44

So this sample input would be
3
5
7 14 2 3 5
4
3 1 7 2
3 
2 2 6

and the output is suppose to be 
283
63
44
```

However with using my recursion function like this-

```
def test(cases):
    if cases == 0:
        return 0
    
    else:
        tempNum=int(input())
        tempStr=input()
        tempNumsList=tempStr.split(" ")
        test(cases-1)
        print(sum(tempNum, tempNumsList))
```

The output I get begins with the sum of the final inputs rather than the other way around.

```
44
75
283
```

but if I swapped the print and recursive call The output interrupts the input of each case.

```
def test(cases):
    if cases == 0:
        return 0
    
    else:
        tempNum=int(input())
        tempStr=input()
        tempNumsList=tempStr.split(" ")
        print(sum(tempNum, tempNumsList))  
        test(cases-1)
```

```
IE 
in- 3
in- 5
in- 7 14 2 3 5
out- 283
in- 4 
in- 3 1 7 2
out- 75
in- 3 
in- 2 2 6
out- 44
```

how can I make the output all happen after the input without it reversing the order because of how recursive stacks work?

Here is the entirety of my code if that helps.

```
import math

def test(cases):
    if cases == 0:
        return 0
    
    else:
        tempNum=int(input())
        tempStr=input()
        tempNumsList=tempStr.split(" ")
        test(cases-1)
        print(sum(tempNum, tempNumsList))  
      
def sum(nums, numsList):
    if nums==0:
        return 0
    
    else:
        if (int(numsList[0]) >=1):
            temp =int(numsList[0])
            tempList = numsList
            tempList.pop(0)
            return int(math.pow(temp,2) + sum(nums-1, tempList))
        
        tempList = numsList
        tempList.pop(0)
        return sum(nums-1, numsList)

def main():
    test(int(input()))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As Stated above I have tried moving where my the position of my print statement but that change makes the the output interrupt the input. I have also tried making the recursive call inside the print statement itself but that causing the program to print the solutions many time. I've also tried calling the print from the main method but that leads to only getting a singular sum to print rather than all of the sums.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no elegant solution to your problem, as recursion works like a boomerang. A solution that I propose to you is to store the values in a list and define another function that recursively prints the stored values.

```
import math

solutionList = []
repeats = int(input())

def test(cases):
    if cases == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        tempNum = int(input())
        tempStr = input()
        tempNumsList = tempStr.split(" ")
        test(cases - 1)
        #print(sum(tempNum, tempNumsList))
        solutionList.append(sum(tempNum, tempNumsList))

def sum(nums, numsList):
    if nums == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        if (int(numsList[0]) >= 1):
            temp = int(numsList[0])
            tempList = numsList
            tempList.pop(0)
            return int(math.pow(temp, 2) + sum(nums - 1, tempList))

        tempList = numsList
        tempList.pop(0)
        return sum(nums - 1, numsList)


def printSolutions(case):
    if case == 0:
        return 0

    else:
        print(solutionList[case-1])
        printSolutions(case-1)


test(repeats)
printSolutions(repeats)
```

As said, it is not an elegant solution but it does the trick.

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: This solution help significantly for now I will implement it but will continue to look for other option while I can since I receive extra credit it I can accomplish it without needed to declare a global variable. The credit itself isn't honestly what's important but learning from the exercise is. Thank you for your response!